# Different customs for Ashkenazic and Sephardic weddings

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, wedding, ashkenazi

What are the major differences that one would notice between a Sephardic and an Ashkenazic wedding?

Comment: Last names.....

Comment: Sefardim don't do a badeikin

Comment: sefardim have the chupa indoors sometimes

Comment: @sam - nor do many yekkes.

Comment: @m.r. - so do others, including Yekkes and the Atlanta "Beth Jacob" shul, to name a few.

Answer (score 3):

A few that come to mind. By the Sefardic wedding the Chasan makes a Shehechiyanu and puts on a new Talis under the Chupa, which is not done by the Ashkenazim. By the Sefardic wedding the Chasan leaves the Chupa and goes to greet the Kalla as she is coming down the aisle, which is not done by the Ashkenazim.

Comment: I've seen both of these at Ashkenazi weddings (different ones).

Comment: Before my wedding I told my wife to be to keep her Sfardi minhag and stop halfway down the aisle, and I would keep to my Ashkenazi minhag and stay under the chupa:)

Answer (score 3):

Sephardim don't have a cheder yichud. In Israel, they swear under the chupa not to marry another woman (while still married).